# Opening an Empty Directory from a Windows Form - VB.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, directory

I'm trying to open a directory via my Windows Form created in VB.Net but every solution I've found doesn't seem to work.

Currently I'm using-

```
Dim path As String = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()

Private Sub logDirBTN_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles logDirBTN.Click
    Process.Start(path + "\Resources\Logs")
End Sub
```

Which returns "The system cannot find the file specified" exception. That's interesting because I know the folder is there. Furthermore this button's functionality works without any issue and from what I can tell the only difference is I'm opening a text file rather than an empty directory-

```
Private Sub stationListBTN_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles stationListBTN.Click
    Process.Start("notepad.exe", path + "\Resources\StationList\StationList.txt")
End Sub
```

Here are all the other things I've tried-

```
Private Sub logDirBTN_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles logDirBTN.Click
    'Process.Start("explorer.exe", path + "\Resources\Logs")
    'Shell("explorer.exe", path + "\Resources\Logs", vbNormalFocus)
    'Application.StartupPath & path + "\Resources\Logs"
    'Shell(path + "\Resources\Logs", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It requires the path to a file, a directory cannot work.  If you want to open an Explorer view on the directory then start Explorer.exe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim MyProcess As New Process()
MyProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "explorer.exe"
MyProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "C:\Blah"
MyProcess.Start()
MyProcess.WaitForExit()
MyProcess.Close()
MyProcess.Dispose()
```

Or just...

```
Process.Start("explorer.exe", "C:\FTP\")
```

Application.StartupPath is going to get you to your bin\Debug or bin\Release folder by the way, whatever folder the *.exe is in.

I'm guessing this is what you're looking for:

```
Process.Start("explorer.exe", Application.StartupPath & "\Resources\Logs")
```

Also, don't use `+` for joining strings. Use `&`

Comment: What if I need to use the path that the application is run from? For my purposes a static path will not work.

Comment: I forgot to set the file inside the directory to "Always copy" and so the directory wasn't being created which is why the program couldn't find the file. Your answer about the Application.StartupPath led me to this conclusion. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are trying to invoke Windows Explorer.

Add a trailing \ in the call to .Start

```
    IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\temp\temp")
    Process.Start("c:\temp\temp\")
```

In the OP first example you were trying to open a file 'Logs'